# Getting Scale Bar, WebMap with GeoExt?

Tags: geoext, scale-bar

I tried to make a WebMap with GeoExt and everything is working, but I don't see a scalebar.

```
var mapPanel, tree;
    Ext.application({
        name: 'test',
        launch: function() {
           mapPanel = Ext.create('GeoExt.panel.Map', {
                title: 'test',          
                border: true,
                region: "center",
                map: {allOverlays: false},
                center: [14.000000,47.00000],
                zoom: 11, 

              layers: [

                    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenStreetMap",
                        "http://ows.terrestris.de/osm-gray/service?",
                        {layers: 'OSM-WMS' },
                        {
                            attribution: '&copy; terrestris GmbH & Co. KG <br>' +
                                'Data &copy; OpenStreetMap ' +
                                '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/en"' +
                                'target="_blank">contributors<a>'           
                        }
                    ), .... ]

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            model: 'GeoExt.data.LayerTreeModel',
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                   {
                        plugins: ['gx_overlaylayercontainer'],
                        expanded: true,
                        text: "Layer"
                    },
                     {
                        plugins: ['gx_baselayercontainer'],
                        expanded: true,
                        text: "Base Maps"
                    }

                ]
            }
        });

       tree = Ext.create('GeoExt.tree.Panel', {
            border: true,
            region: "west",
            title: "Layers",
            width: 285,
            height: 200,
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: "mini",
            autoScroll: true,
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            lines: false,
            tbar: true  
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
            layout:"fit",
            hideBorders: true,
            items: {
                layout: "border",
                background: "red",
                deferredRender: false,
                items: [mapPanel, tree, {
                    contentEl: "desc",
                    region: "north",
                    bodyStyle: {"padding": "5px"},
                    collapsible: true,
                    collapseMode: "mini",
                    split: true,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 150,
                    title: "test"

                }]
            }
        });

    } 
});
```

How can I change the code to get the scale bar for the OSM?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. You might get better help if you create a working example in jsFiddle or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example define the map as a variable and point to this variable when you create your MapPanel:

```
var your_map=new OpenLayers.Map({allOverlays: false});

mapPanel = Ext.create('GeoExt.panel.Map', {
                title: 'test',          
                border: true,
                region: "center",
                map: your_map,
                center: [14.000000,47.00000],
                .......  // your other settings
              });

var your_scalebar=new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(); 
your_map.addControl(your_scalebar);
```

Edit1: jsfiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/rxr2mhee/

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to create an OpenLayers control and display it on your map.

```
new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({})
```

Documentation [found here.](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ScaleLine-js.html)

Looks like GeoExt explains a little on OpenLayers controls [here also.](http://geoext.org/primers/openlayers-primer.html#controls)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try the OpenLayers control and tell you if I got it.